# DataFrame partitionBy to a single Parquet file (per partition)

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I would like to repartition / coalesce my data so that it is saved into one Parquet file per partition.  I would also like to use the Spark SQL partitionBy API.  So I could do that like this:

```
df.coalesce(1)
    .write
    .partitionBy("entity", "year", "month", "day", "status")
    .mode(SaveMode.Append)
    .parquet(s"$location")
```

I've tested this and it doesn't seem to perform well.  This is because there is only one partition to work on in the dataset and all the partitioning, compression and saving of files has to be done by one CPU core.

I could rewrite this to do the partitioning manually (using filter with the distinct partition values for example) before calling coalesce.

But is there a better way to do this using the standard Spark SQL API?

Comment: Did you find the solution yet?

Answer (score 125, accepted):

I had the exact same problem and I found a way to do this using `DataFrame.repartition()`. The problem with using `coalesce(1)` is that your parallelism drops to 1, and it can be slow at best and error out at worst. Increasing that number doesn't help either -- if you do `coalesce(10)` you get more parallelism, but end up with 10 files per partition.

To get one file per partition without using `coalesce()`, use `repartition()` with the same columns you want the output to be partitioned by. So in your case, do this:

```
import spark.implicits._
df
  .repartition($"entity", $"year", $"month", $"day", $"status")
  .write
  .partitionBy("entity", "year", "month", "day", "status")
  .mode(SaveMode.Append)
  .parquet(s"$location")
```

Once I do that I get one parquet file per output partition, instead of multiple files.

I tested this in Python, but I assume in Scala it should be the same.

Comment: I guess @PatrickMcGloin didn't report back, but this works beautifully and I will encourage Patrick to accept the answer.

Comment: @GlennieHellesSindholt - you are right.  Answer accepted.  Thanks user3033652.

Comment: just a note that in scala 2.0 one needs to give a new org.apache.spark.sql.Column("entity") etc. as argument to repartition

Comment: @morpheus Or simply `$"entity"`.

Comment: Using Spark 1.6 this works perfectly for Parquet. However, with Avro I still end up with multiple files per partition.

Comment: @morpheus I'm getting `org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Cannot use all columns for partition columns` even though I'm using only 4 columns out of 30. Any ideas?

Comment: Is there any place this difference between `coalesce` and `repartition` is better explained? Specifically the implications for write parallelism.

Comments in code: https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset.scala#L2862-L2881

Comment: Did someone found a way to implement this in pyspark as above example does not work.
in Pyspark import pyspark.implicits._ or import spark.implicits._ does not exist and also the parameter SaveMode.Append is unknown

Comment: Keep in mind that you'll get `spark.sql.shuffle.partitions` partitions. You can always use `repartition(numPartitions: Int, partitionExprs: Column*)` if you know how many files you should expect on the file system

Comment: How do you use $ notation in PySpark??

Comment: you don't need any $ notation in pyspark, just use strings

Comment: example:
* create dataframe =>
`df = spark.createDataFrame({('test', 1, .1), ('test', 2, .2), ('test2', 3, .3)}, 'a: string, b: int, c: float')`
* partition and save =>
`df.repartition('a', 'b').write.partitionBy('a', 'b').mode('append').parquet('output')`

Comment: why will number of files not be equal to number of partitions? 200 by default?

Comment: should be        .mode( saveMode="overwrite").parquet("path")

Answer (score 10):

By definition :

> coalesce(numPartitions: Int): DataFrame
>   Returns a new DataFrame that has exactly numPartitions partitions.

You can use it to decrease the number of partitions in the RDD/DataFrame with the numPartitions parameter. It's useful for running operations more efficiently after filtering down a large dataset.

Concerning your code, it doesn't perform well because what you are actually doing is :

1. putting everything into 1 partition which overloads the driver since it's pull all the data into 1 partition on the driver (and also it not a good practice)
2. `coalesce` actually shuffles all the data on the network which may also result in performance loss.

> The shuffle is Spark’s mechanism for re-distributing data so that it’s grouped differently across partitions. This typically involves copying data across executors and machines, making the shuffle a complex and costly operation.

The **shuffle** concept is very important to manage and understand. It's always preferable to shuffle the minimum possible because it is an expensive operation since it involves disk I/O, data serialization, and network I/O. To organize data for the shuffle, Spark generates sets of tasks - map tasks to organize the data, and a set of reduce tasks to aggregate it. This nomenclature comes from MapReduce and does not directly relate to Spark’s map and reduce operations.

Internally, results from individual map tasks are kept in memory until they can’t fit. Then, these are sorted based on the target partition and written to a single file. On the reduce side, tasks read the relevant sorted blocks.

Concerning partitioning parquet, I suggest that you read the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32588710/spark-dataframes-with-parquet-and-partitioning) about Spark DataFrames with Parquet Partitioning and also this [section](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#performance-tuning) in the Spark Programming Guide for **Performance Tuning**.

I hope this helps !

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply.  I'm fine with the coalesce having a cost.  In my current code I partition the data manually, then call coalesce and save on each partition which runs fine.  But instead of writing the partitionBy step myself I'd like to use the proper API.  But in doing so, the coalesce has to come before the partitionBy.  That's where I'm stuck.

Comment: But what you are doing is putting everything in 1 partition and then partitionBy, you ought just partitionBy instead

Comment: But then I end up with many files.  I want to limit the number of Parquet files created.  I'm streaming and saving once per minute, so every partition already has 1440 files.  I don't want to multiply that.

Comment: Ok let me put it this way, your code will write a parquet file per partition to file system (local or HDFS). This means that if you have 10 distinct entity and 3 distinct years for 12 months each, etc  you might end up creating 1440 files.

Comment: I think there is crossed wires.  I am streaming the data in and calling save every minute.  So as long as there is data for that partition, it will get a new file every minute.  SaveMode.Append in Parquet creates a new file.

Comment: @zero323 what do you think about this ?

Comment: I still don't know how to efficiently save data into one Parquet file per partition using the standard API, so I don't think it answers the question.

Comment: @PatrickMcGloin If I may ask, how many partition do you think that your DataFrame should have ?

Comment: Ha, sorry.  Per day around 10.

Comment: and how many unique ("entity", "year", "month", "day", "status") tuple do you have ? I would say 1440...

Comment: @eliasah, thank you ...
I have a huge data , which is accumalated each year , quarterly-wise.
This data is skewed a bit , when I try to get all data into one dataframe by repartitoning it into ("year", "quarter") it is shuffling a lot of data on disk spill which is making my job slow , more over only one executor working 80% of the time.
Hence I decided to 
1) get distinct groups of dataframe , grouping by year and quarter-wise.
2) iterate/loop this distinct data frame by group
   fetch the data group where = year of the group
   save this dataframe/grop as parquet file

Comment: @eliasah continue iteration.
In Java we can use for loop on groups
but in spark with scala how to do it ?

your help is highly appreciated.

Comment: @eliasah Hence I decided to 
1) get distinct groups of dataframe , grouping by year and quarter-wise.
2) iterate/loop this distinct data frame by group ;
   fetch the data group where = year of the group ; 
   save this dataframe/grop as parquet file ; 
   continue iteration;;;;
In Java we can use for loop on groups
but in spark with scala how to do it ?

Answer (score 0):

It isn't much on top of @mortada's solution, but here's a little abstraction that ensures you are using the same partitioning to repartition and write, and demonstrates sorting as wel:

```py
  def one_file_per_partition(df, path, partitions, sort_within_partitions, VERBOSE = False):
    start = datetime.now()
    (df.repartition(*partitions)
      .sortWithinPartitions(*sort_within_partitions)
      .write.partitionBy(*partitions)
      # TODO: Format of your choosing here
      .mode(SaveMode.Append).parquet(path)
      # or, e.g.:
      #.option("compression", "gzip").option("header", "true").mode("overwrite").csv(path)
    )
    print(f"Wrote data partitioned by {partitions} and sorted by {sort_within_partitions} to:" +
        f"\n  {path}\n  Time taken: {(datetime.now() - start).total_seconds():,.2f} seconds")
```

Usage:

```
one_file_per_partition(df, location, ["entity", "year", "month", "day", "status"])
```