# PySpark: Writing input files to separate output files without repartitioning

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, parquet

I have a sequence of very large daily gzipped files. I'm trying to use PySpark to re-save all the files in S3 in Parquet format for later use.

If for a single file (in example, 2012-06-01) I do:

```
dataframe = spark.read.csv('s3://mybucket/input/20120601.gz', schema=my_schema, header=True)
dataframe.write.parquet('s3://mybucket/output/20120601')
```

it works, but since gzip isn't splittable it runs on a single host and I get no benefit of using the cluster.

I tried reading in a chunk of files at once, and using partitionBy to write the output to daily files like this (in example, reading in a month):

```
dataframe = spark.read.csv('s3://mybucket/input/201206*.gz', schema=my_schema, header=True)
dataframe.write.partitionBy('dayColumn').parquet('s3://mybucket/output/')
```

This time, individual files are read in different executors like I want, but the executors later die and the process fails. I believe since the files are so large, and the partitionBy is somehow using unnecessary resources (a shuffle?) it's crashing the tasks.

I don't actually need to re-partition my dataframe since this is just a 1:1 mapping. Is there anyway to make each individual task write to a separate, explicitly named parquet output file?

I was thinking something like

```
def write_file(date):
    # get input/output locations from date
    dataframe = spark.read.csv(input_location, schema=my_schema, header=True)
    dataframe.write.parquet(output_location)
spark.sparkContext.parallelize(my_dates).for_each(write_file)
```

except this doesn't work since you can't broadcast the spark session to the cluster. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

> Writing input files to separate output files without repartitioning

**TL;DR** This is what your code is already doing.

> partitionBy is causing a unnecessary shuffle

No. `DataFrameWriter.partitionBy` doesn't shuffle at all.

> it works, but since gzip isn't splittable

You can:

- Drop compression completely - Parquet uses internal compression.
- Use splittable compression like `bzip2`.
- Unpack the files to a temporary storage before submitting the job.

If you are concerned about resources used by `partitionBy` (it might open larger number of files for each executor thread) you can actually shuffle to improve performance - [DataFrame partitionBy to a single Parquet file (per partition)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34789604/8371915). Single file is probably to much but

```
dataframe \
    .repartition(n, 'dayColumn', 'someOtherColumn') \
    .write.partitionBy('dayColumn') \
    .save(...)
```

where `someOtherColumn` can be chosen to get reasonable cardinality, should improve things.

Comment: Meant that gzip isn't splittable, was a typo. I've tested, and the problem is definitely the partitionBy. If I run the exact same command, but without partitonBy it works, except the output files aren't named properly. With partitionBy, the executor nodes repeatedly kill themselves. My presumption was a shuffle has to be happening to cause this, but something is definitely using unnecessary resources with the partitonBy.