# Parallelize File operations on the spark driver

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, databricks

I'm trying to delete a large number of files on blob, mounted to my spark driver.

When I do this in a for loop, each operation carries some latency and it takes minutes.

If I do this locally from my desktop, I can delete all the files in a few seconds, but I would like this to be done automatically by the spark driver (a sort of "clean-up" routine)

---

**What I've tried**

When I attempt to parallelize this using spark, I get the error:

> You cannot use dbutils within a spark job or otherwise pickle it.

Example:

```py
toDelete = getFilesFromVariousFoldersToDelete()
spark.createDataFrame([p for p in toDelete], StringType()) \
  .foreach(lambda r: dbutils.fs.rm(r[0]))
```

---

When I try to parallelize on the driver using native python "multiprocessing.Pool", I get the error:

> cannot pickle "_thread.RLock"

Example:

```py
toDelete = getFilesFromVariousFoldersToDelete()
if(len(toDelete) > 0):
  Pool(len(toDelete)).map(dbutils.fs.rm, toDelete)
```

Is there an "approved" method for doing a lot of (network) file I/O in parallel in databricks / spark?

Comment: What filesystem are you using underneath? I remember I've run into this a while back when working with S3 and eventually gave up on `dbutils` and used `boto3` instead...

Comment: @Moritz it's a mounted blob system, but you're right, seems the solution is to give up on dbutils.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution ended up being that I had to abandon `dbutils` and learn how to construct paths that could be recognized by `os`.

It turned out to be not too bad - `dbutils` wants you to reference paths from the root `/mnt/` (mount folder). All that's needed to use `os` is to prepend `/dbfs` to this. The solution gets a little more complex, because dbutils.rm would handle files or folders, so we need to split it into two steps (although we can probably just come up with a more elaborate lambda)

```py
toDelete = getVariousFilesAndFoldersToDelete()
delete_files = [d for d in toDelete if d[-1] != "/"]
delete_folders = [d for d in toDelete if d[-1] == "/"]
spark.createDataFrame(delete_files, StringType()).foreach(lambda r: os.remove(r[0]))
spark.createDataFrame(delete_folders, StringType()).foreach(lambda r: os.rmdir(r[0]))
```

The result is file operations are parallelized across all available spark executors and takes significantly less time.

I haven't tested whether Pool can be used now that dbutils is out of the picture, if so, performance stands to be even better, even if you're stuck on the driver, because you can over-subscribe your cores with threads just sat waiting for an IO operation to complete.

---

**edit**

I also tried with pool:

```py
Pool(len(delete_files)).map(os.remove, delete_files)
Pool(len(delete_folders)).map(os.rmdir, delete_folders)
```

And the result was faster than sequential, but much slower than using spark executors. I can only guess that despite creating a pool with as many threads as file operations that need to be done, they did not all start at the same time.

Comment: If anyone is curious, I used this approach as part of a generic solution to writing partitioned data to disk, organized in a human-readable way, producing a single file per partition: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72035183/529618