# Spark parallelize and partition by key

Tags: apache-spark

In Spark, I can do

```
sc.parallelize([(0, 0), (1, 1), (0, 2), (1, 3), (0, 4), (1, 5)], 2).partitionBy(2)
```

However, this first distributes the data across the nodes of the cluster, only to then shuffle it again. Is there a way to partition by key immediately when the data are entered from the driver program?

Comment: It is possible to avoid data movement by organizing local data first but it looks like an artificial issue. You should never use `parallelize` to pass data that is large enough for a subsequent shuffle to be an issue.

Answer (score 0):

In the example that you had provided, Spark is not aware of partitioning of the data until you are going to explicitly mention that via `partitionByKey()`.

But Spark can leverage the natural partitioning of the data if it is already organized in the appropriate way. For instance,

- for Spark, Parquet and HDFS there are the specific set of rules, [Spark DataFrames with Parquet and Partitioning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32588710/spark-dataframes-with-parquet-and-partitioning)
- for Spark and Cassandra, you can use specific APIs from Cassandra Connector to leverage partitioning https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/3_selection.md#grouping-rows-by-partition-key
- etc.

So nature of data, file system, etc. will influence partitioning in Spark.